# How to get the max N elements

Tags: python

I know how to get a single max:

```
m = max([1,2])
2
```

How would I get the max `n` elements? For example:

```
m = max([1,2,3,4,5], n=2)
[4,5]
```

Comment: `sorted(whatever)[-2:]`?

Answer (score 13):

```
import heapq
input_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
number_of_elements = 3
heapq.nlargest(number_of_elements, input_list)
```

For more info, here are the [heap queue algorithm docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

Comment: By far the best approach!

Comment: You can see a discution about time complexity here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23038756/4660239

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to implement it - sort the list, then slice the first `n` elements.

```
def maxN(elements, n):
    return sorted(elements, reverse=True)[:n]
```

Comment: This is not the most efficient way to find the max n elements, since sorting the entire list may not be necessary if all you need is the top few values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to beat the performance of a sorting algo you need to use a select algorithm (like QuickSelect)

see : [quickSelect HW in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12920508/4660239)

This reduces the average complexity from O(n log n) (in quicksort) to O(n) (in quickselect).